# IE8 Ignoring Background rules for Fancybox 2 ... Black background regardless of Fancybox CSS

Tags: internet-explorer-8, fancybox

I am using Fancybox v2.1.4 throughout a site with no problem, except in ie8 (even ie7 is ok).  When I apply fancybox to a div in ie8, all background css is lost.

Here is what it is supposed to look like, and looks great in all browsers but ie8:
http://hallyb.com/images/good.jpg

And here is how it renders in ie8:
http://hallyb.com/images/bad.jpg

Nothing I change with the fancybox.css affects this black background; in fact, the background color is set to #fff first, with a background image added second  Nothing about it says "black".

Thanks for any insight to this problem.

Comment: pictures don't help, your code or a link to the site with the issue would be more efficient

Comment: sure, the development server is http://166.78.86.20
... the "Login" button at the top right is where i'm running into the fancybox issue.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

This one was tricky because I am using PIE (http://css3pie.com) to wonderfully render css3 effects in older IE.  For some reason, IE8 does not like it when the PIE.htc behavior file is called on nested elements, such as the fancybox 'wrap' code I am using here.  IE7 doesn't seem to care.  Remove the duplicate behavior attribute from the fancybox css and all is well.